# Undefined index on file upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I have next code :

which works great on other pages. But not on this

```
<tr><td>Upload Terms and Condition <br />(pdf, doc, docx, xls, txt)</td>
    <td><input type = "file" name = "termspdf" id = "termspdf"/></td>
</tr>
```

and next code is :

```
// PDF SECTION ...
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['termspdf']['tmp_name'])) {
    $pdf = $_FILES["termspdf"]["name"];
    $pdfSize = $_FILES["termspdf"]["size"];


    if ($_FILES['termspdf']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
        echo $lang['var464'];
    } else {
        $path="images/products/pdf/";
        $newPdf = time().".pdf";
        $newPDFPath=$path.$newPdf;

        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['termspdf']['tmp_name'], $newPDFPath);
        chmod($newPDFPath, 0777);
    }
}




Array
(
)
```

> Notice: Undefined index: termspdf in
>   /home/user678/public_html/users/_edit.php on line 25

I get any result. What can be wrong?

```
print "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
```

nothing ..

Thank you

Comment: Check that the input type "file" is inside the form element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is probably not a multipart form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action= "<?=BASE_URL?>/user.php?do=edit" method="POST">
```

Comment: <form method="post" class="mydetayls"  id="mydetayls" name="mydetayls" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"> My form is multipart.

Comment: Also ... all other fields are uploaded right.

Comment: Do you happen to have another field with `name="termspdf"` by any chance then?

Comment: I had checked all website . Not any name="termspdf" field.. Very weird.

Comment: thank you BOTH For your answers ... SOLVED action="<?=BASE_URL?>/user.php?do=edit" --- WRONG ACTION TAG

Answer (score 0):

maybe your file is too large?
see in php.ini `upload_max_filesize` and post_max_size

also you can check `$_FILES['termspdf']['error']`